# Drop Http request in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, servlets

I have a spring controller with some handler methods. Something like this:

```
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    if (requestShallNotPass(httpServletRequest)) {
        // ignore the request and don't send the response
        return;
    }

    // business logic ... 
}
```

Some of the requests needs to be dropped based on a custom logic and the response never sent to client. Doing a return in `doPost()` still sends an empty response to client.

What would be the right way to ignore that request?

Comment: what do you want to see in response with that request? nothing? none status, none smth???

Comment: I believe that is against HTTP standard. Every request has to have a reasponse. You have to send a HTTP status code. If you don't send any response, the client will get a HTTP timeout eventually.

Comment: @Dred if the request shall be processed, I'll set various fields and and a body to that response. otherwise I want to completely ignore it.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi I guess, but is not mandatory. What if there is boot or a spammer? In this case I want to save bandwidth and cpu time by not processing the request at all.

Comment: Send a 204 No content response.

Comment: you may try to make fake exception like `throw new Exception();` maybe it helps you, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Dred actually the doPost has a throws ServletException in the signature ```void doPost(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException``` I'll try to throw it.

Comment: @DanielTung somehow, but no valid response is in there.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi If I send a response at all, this means more bandwidth. In the scenario I have, there can be a lot of spam traffic which can bring an overhead to the whole system.

Comment: What you are trying to do goes against the HTTP standard. Spring does not handle the HTTP connection itself and this is done at a much lower level. You could try breaking into the HTTP connection handler and forcing the connection to be closed without responding but you'll just end up creating a timeout. The only times killing connections with no response is seen as acceptable is at firewall levels during attacks where by you don't want to respond to the client to save time and bandwidth.

Comment: @DanielTung this explains a lot, thanks! I guess I'll just go with ```throw new ServletException("blocked")``` which will send 500 Internal Server Error to client

Comment: @vasile_t The better option would be to return a 404 in my opinion. This way you're not giving any information to 'attackers' as they'll get the same response as if requesting an endpoint that doesn't exist. Returning a 500 proves to them that there's something there that they didn't interact with correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't be sending a 500, as it would mean an error in processing by the server. Ideal way would be to send a 400 bad request.